# Is there a "modern UI" equivalent to ClientPeoplePicker?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, people-picker, people-search, clientpeoplepicker

Is there a SharePoint "modern UI" equivalent to the SP ClientPeoplePicker control? I've seen the [Fabric UI control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/peoplepicker), but that's just the interface component, and doesn't handle user search/resolution.

Or, if one was to build a custom people picker, what's the best approach for resolving users by partial name searches? It seems Microsoft has disabled the ability for external users to get People results back from search, and calling EnsureUser or searching the Profile service requires having the full login ID (doesn't it?). <strike>The people picker calls some kind of user search, but I haven't found any documentation on that service/endpoint.</strike>

Edit: It seems that if I need to build a custom one, I should use the `/_api/SP.UI.ApplicationPages.ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.clientPeoplePickerSearchUser` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There's the experimental people picker widget

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-experimental-people-picker-widget-in-sharepoint-add-ins

but it seems to require a whole lot of extra library references so you will probably need to go through the docs...

Comment: That looks interesting, but it doesn't have the "modern UI" look I'm seeing in regular People Pickers in SP modern sites/lists, and it's probably too early for production use. Best thing I've found in my searches so far is this, which I'd have to use the Fabric UI controls for, but I can at least resolve users without additional JS libraries: https://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-clientpeoplepicker.html